# How to use StandardScaler on subset of columns in pyspark ml pipeline?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

In my dataFrame, some columns are continuous values, and other columns just has 0/1 values. I want to use StandardScaler on continuous columns before logistic regression with Pipeline. How to implement the code?

I try:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler,StandardScaler
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline,Transformer
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf,col
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType, ArrayType
from pyspark.ml.util import DefaultParamsWritable, DefaultParamsReadable
from pyspark.ml.param.shared import HasInputCol, HasOutputCol, Param, Params, TypeConverters

class StandardScalerSubset(Transformer, DefaultParamsReadable, DefaultParamsWritable):
    """
    A custom Transformer which use StandardScaler on subset of features.
    """
    def __init__(self, to_scale_cols, remaining_cols):
        super(StandardScalerSubset, self).__init__()
        self.to_scale_cols = to_scale_cols  # continuous columns to be scaled
        self.remaining_cols = remaining_cols  # other columns

    def _transform(self, data):
        va = VectorAssembler().setInputCols(self.to_scale_cols).setOutputCol("to_scale_vector")
        data_va = va.transform(data)

        scaler = StandardScaler(inputCol="to_scale_vector", outputCol="scaled_vector", withMean=True, withStd=True)
        scaler_model = scaler.fit(data_va)
        data_scaled = scaler_model.transform(data_va)

        vector2list = udf(lambda x: x.toArray().tolist(),ArrayType(FloatType()))
        # return all columns
        data_res = data_scaled.withColumn("scaled_list", vector2list("scaled_vector")) \
            .select(self.remaining_cols
                    + [col("scaled_list").getItem(i).alias(c) for (i, c) in enumerate(self.scale_cols)])
        return data_res
```

For input:

```
# +---+---+---+---+
# |  a|  b|  c|  d|
# +---+---+---+---+
# |  1|  5| 10|  0|
# |  0| 10| 20|  1|
# |  1| 15| 25|  0|
# |  0| 30| 40|  1|
# +---+---+---+---+
```

The output would be:

```
# +---+---+--------+-----+
# |  a|  d|       b|    c|
# +---+---+--------+-----+
# |  1|  0| -0.9258| -1.1|
# |  0|  1| -0.4629| -0.3|
# |  1|  0|     0.0|  0.1|
# |  0|  1|  1.3887|  1.3|
# +---+---+--------+-----+
```

It just can be used like this:

```
scalerFeatures = ['xxx']
featureAr = ['xxx']
remainingFeatures = ['xxx']
sss = StandardScalerSubset(scale_cols=scalerFeatures, remaining_cols=remainingFeatures)
vectorAssembler = VectorAssembler().setInputCols(featureArr).setOutputCol("features")
lrModel = LogisticRegression(featuresCol="features",regParam=0.1,maxIter=100,family="binomial")
pipeline = Pipeline().setStages([sss, vectorAssembler, modelObject])
pipeline.fit(trainData).write().overwrite().save(modelSavePath)
```

When I use PipelineModel.load(modelSavePath) to load model, I get error.
I think that I should implement **fit** and **transform** at the same time. However I don't know how to do that. Can Anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too long for a comment, but here's what you can try:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StandardScaler
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

scalerFeatures = ['b', 'c']
remainingFeatures = ['a', 'd']
featureArr = remainingFeatures + [('scaled_' + f) for f in scalerFeatures]

va1 = [VectorAssembler(inputCols=[f], outputCol=('vec_' + f)) for f in scalerFeatures]
ss = [StandardScaler(inputCol='vec_' + f, outputCol='scaled_' + f, withMean=True, withStd=True) for f in scalerFeatures]

va2 = VectorAssembler(inputCols=featureArr, outputCol="features")
lr = LogisticRegression()

stages = va1 + ss + [va2]
# I don't have a label column, but if you do, you can put lr stage at the end:
# stages = va1 + ss + [va2, lr]

p = Pipeline(stages=stages)
p.fit(df).transform(df).show()
+---+---+---+---+------+------+---------------------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
|a  |b  |c  |d  |vec_b |vec_c |scaled_b             |scaled_c              |features                                          |
+---+---+---+---+------+------+---------------------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
|1  |5  |10 |0  |[5.0] |[10.0]|[-0.9258200997725514]|[-1.0999999999999999] |[1.0,0.0,-0.9258200997725514,-1.0999999999999999] |
|0  |10 |20 |1  |[10.0]|[20.0]|[-0.4629100498862757]|[-0.29999999999999993]|[0.0,1.0,-0.4629100498862757,-0.29999999999999993]|
|1  |15 |25 |0  |[15.0]|[25.0]|[0.0]                |[0.09999999999999998] |[1.0,0.0,0.0,0.09999999999999998]                 |
|0  |30 |40 |1  |[30.0]|[40.0]|[1.3887301496588271] |[1.2999999999999998]  |[0.0,1.0,1.3887301496588271,1.2999999999999998]   |
+---+---+---+---+------+------+---------------------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```